# Cannot reopen an Activity after opening another Activity

Tags: javascript, android

i tried too open an activity in this flow :

Activity1(directly from notification) -> MainActivity(onBackPress from Activity1) -> Activity1(from MainActivity)

but for some reason i cannot open Activity1(from MainActivity), and my logcat did not print any errors or warnings.

and also i can open Activity1(from MainActivity) normally if i just start MainActivity on apps launch without opening Activity1(directly from notification) first.

here is some code

1. this from notification to open Activity1

   ```js
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
   startActivity(inten);
   ```
2. this from Activity1 onBackPress going to MainActivity

```js
Intent inten=new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);    
inten.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(inten);
```

3. lastly this from MainActivity to open Activity1

```js
Intent go = new Intent(context,Activity1.class);
go.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(go);
```

and for a note i open Activity1 from MainActivity not directly but from an adapter class of recyclerview, thats why there is "FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK" flag there.

please help me, did i miss something or else ?

thanks before.

addition :

```js
public Adapterbanner(Context context, List<ObjectVoucher> itemList, int wdth) {
        this.itemList = itemList;
        this.context = context;
        this.wdth= wdth;
    }
```

logcat print :

```js
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.xxx.xxx time:32028626
```

finnaly found the problem, i just need to add this flag :

```js
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Intent go = new Intent(context,Activity1.class);
go.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(go);
```

When you use `setFlags` you are replacing the old flags... when you use `addFlags` you are appending new flags...

in Recylerview adapter:

```
 private final Context context;

public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    context = itemView.getContext();
    ...
}
```

now use the context to start the activity..

Comment: thanks for your answer, i tried but it still didn't work.

Comment: post ur recylerview adapter code...did u get context like the edit?

Comment: did u set the adapter like this:`list.setadapter(new Adapterbanner(MainActivity .this,,...));`

Comment: a bit different, its like this :list.setadapter new Adapterbanner(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),...));

because its from fragment

Comment: also the is this print on logcat : "I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.xxx.xxx time:32028626" like usual but just nothing came out

Answer (score 0):

If you are going back to your first [Main] Activity, then you don't have to put any piece of code at second activity [where you got switched].

Just Put this below code at method "onClick" in FirstActivity

```
Intent change = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(change);
```

When backbutton is pressed at SecondActivity it will automatically switch to FirstActivity [If not android:launchMode="singleInstance" is written to Mainfest]

Comment: that is not the case here, i am not going back to my first [Main] activity, i bypass it to second activity and opening the first activity from there, and then open the second activity again from main activity.

Answer (score 0):

finnaly found the problem, i just need to add this flag so it become:

```js
Intent go = new Intent(context,Activity1.class);           
go.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(go);
```

this works for me.